# AngularJS Form Validation inside an ng-repeat

Tags: validation, angularjs

So I am trying to validate the input of one item inside of an ng-repeat.  For examples sake lets say that I have 5 items (1,2,3,4,5) and I only want to validate the form if the 4th item is selected.

I have used ng-pattern before to validate forms, but not one that had a dropdown menu to select item.name

I have included the regex I would like the 4th item to be validated with inside the ng-pattern.

```
<div>
  <select name="name" ng-model="item.name" ng-options="item for item in items" required></select>
</div>

<div>
  <input name="results" type="text" ng-model="item.results" ng-pattern="/^\d\d\d\/\d\d\d/" required>
</div>
```

Any suggestions as to the correct way to validate this situation would be greatly appreciated.  I have thought about creating a directive to validate this, but that feels like is an overly complicated solution to this since I would not use the directive more than once in this app.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

It wouldn't let me answer my own question so here is the answer I figured out.

What I ended up having to do was use ng-pattern and pass it a function.

```
<input name="results" type="text" ng-model="vital.results" ng-pattern="vitalRegEx()" required>
```

Here is the controller code

```
$scope.item4RegEx = /^\d{2,3}\/\d{2,3}$/;

  $scope.itemRegEx = function() {
    if($scope.item && $scope.item.name === "fourth item")
      return $scope.item4RegEx;
    else return (/^$/);
  };
```

Comment: you can write a directive that execute a function on select or blur event on the select widget.

Answer (score 0):

or else...

add ng-change directive on the select dropdown which calls a Controller method and that controller method sets a flag whether to validate form or not.

eg.

```
<select ng-change="checkIfFormShouldbeValidated()" ng-model="item.name"></select>

// Inside controller
$scope.checkIfFromShouldBeValidated = function(){
   if( $scope.item.name == 4th Item ) $scope.shouldValidate = true;
   else $scope.shouldValidate = false;
};


$scope.formSubmit = function(){ 
    if(($scope.shouldValidate && form.$valid) || (!$scope.shouldValidate)){
        // Submit Form  
    } 
};
```

See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this recursive function inside my controller to check the validity of all child scopes.

```
function allValid(scope) {
    var valid = true;
    if (scope.$$childHead) {
        valid = valid && allValid(scope.$$childHead);
    }
    if (scope.$$nextSibling) {
        valid = valid && allValid(scope.$$nextSibling);
    }
    if (scope.scorePlannerForm) {
        valid = valid && scope.myForm.$valid;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Then in my controller I check this with the controller scope.

```
function formSubmit() {
      if (allValid($scope)) {
           // perform save
      }
}
```